# Watch in k8s golang api watches and get events but after sometime doesn't get any more events

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm using AKS and K8s golang API.

I'm creating a Kubernetes watcher for watching jobs like

```
watchres, error := jobsClient.Watch(metav1.ListOptions{})
```

After that i'm getting the events channel like

```
eventres := watchres.ResultChan()
```

After that i'm getting events in a loop using

```
we := <-eventres
```

then on the basis of these event i'm performing some action (for example delete a resource when kubernetes job gets successful)

The issue i am facing is that everything seems to work fine but after some period of time the watcher does not delete resources however the jobs gets successful, what might be the issue, is there a timeout for the channel?? however i'm not closing the channel implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a default timeout on the watch. I believe it is set to 30 minutes.

You can override this value in `ListOptions`. So for example, to set the timeout to an hour:

```
timeout := int64(3600)
watchres, error := jobsClient.Watch(metav1.ListOptions{
    TimeoutSeconds: &timeout,
})
```

Comment: well observing the behavior of watcher i came across the same findings, and now its confirm that i'm hearing it from you. i want to know how can i run watcher till the main thread(listener) ends @philipGough

Comment: You can handle the timeout gracefully just as you might for any other disconnect reason. How will you currently handle it if you need to retry? Or take a look at some blog posts around writing Kubernetes controllers, for example https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-controllers.html.

Comment: I've observed similar behavior as the initial post, even with a timeout set, where it doesn't exit the watch like would happen after timeout, but no more data comes in the channel.  Have not yet solved it :(

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a previous comment, I've had K8s just not feed me more events down the channel, but not actually hangup like the timeout is supposed to.

So I've worked out something here using select - the idea is to wait for events but restart the watcher every 30 minutes just in case K8s doesn't hang up.  So far, this is working:

```
func watchEvents() {
    for {
        if err := RunLoop(); err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func runLoop() error {
    watcher, err := clientset.EventsV1beta1().Events("").Watch(metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ch := watcher.ResultChan()
    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-ch:
            if !ok {
                // the channel got closed, so we need to restart
                log.Info("Kubernetes hung up on us, restarting event watcher")
                return nil
            }

            // handle the event

        case <-time.After(30 * time.Minute):
            // deal with the issue where we get no events
            log.Infof("Timeout, restarting event watcher")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I deployed this yesterday, and it was looking good.... but then it got hung again late last night and didn't actually quit.  So I guess we'll call this a work-in-progress.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't actually got back to this in a while - this was on a much older version of the API than current, I need to do a rewrite of the code. But I essentially followed this pattern, and it does work reasonably.